# Deploy web apps on different ports (JBoss/Wildfly)

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x, wildfly-8

I have 1 application deployed successfully on wildfly server under standalone/deployments and it is working fine.

Now i want to deploy same application with different port on same server for this steps which i've already tried are:-

1. created new folder which is a copy of standalone folder.
2. placed my war file in the folder standalone1/deployments/"war file placed here"
3. Then copied and renamed standalone.sh with standalone1.sh in bin folder.
4. tried starting standalone1.sh by running following command
   "sudo nohup ./standalone1.sh"
5. Server is not started,

Any person can help?

Answer (score 0):

Start second instance with parameter `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset` to avoid port collision and `jboss.server.base.dir` pointing to your cloned standalone folder.

For example running this command starts standalone1 instance on port `8180`.

```
./standalone.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/path/to/jboss/standalone1
```

Do not forget remove folders `standalone1/data` and `standalone1/tmp` before first start of cloned instance, or unpredictable errors may occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
```

By providing value 100 for `jboss.socket.binding.port-offset`, you add "100" to all `portbindings` on the server, very useful for running multiple instances of `JBoss` on the same machine , **to avoid port conflicts.**